# Using tabula-py why I get a list and not a Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, pdf

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tc02g.png)

I want to work with PDF files, specially with tables. I code this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tabula
from tabula import read_pdf
tab= tabula.read_pdf('..\PDFs\Ala.pdf',encoding='latin-1', pages ='all')
tab
```

But I get a list of values, like this:

```
[    Nombres  Edad Ciudad
0    Noelia    20   Lima
1  Michelie    45   Lima
2    Ximena    18   Lima
3    Miguel    43   Lima]
```

I cannot analyze it die it's not a data frame. This is just an example the real PDF file contains tables between texts and several pages

So, please could someone help me with this issue?

Comment: What does `print(type(tab))` display?

Comment: I get <class 'list'>

Comment: So, Could I get it into dataframe?

Comment: Try `tab[0]` is probably a dataframe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tabula` should return a list of Pandas dataframes, one for each table found in the PDF. You could display (and work with them) as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tabula
from tabula import read_pdf

dfs = tabula.read_pdf('..\PDFs\Ala.pdf', encoding='latin-1', pages='all')
print(f"Found {len(dfs)} tables")

# display each of the dataframes
for df in dfs:
    print(df.size)
    print(df)
```

Comment: That's what I need! Thank you! Now I can analyze the data! Awesome!

Comment: To combine the dfs into one df use `df = pd.concat(dfs)`.
Since you tagged it as csv let do that too: `df.to_csv(filepath,index=False)`.  I often remove the index.

Comment: Super @Martin Evans

Answer (score 1):

**tabula** returns a list of Pandas DataFrame. But we can convert this list to Pandas DataFrame using the below statement.

```
import tabula
import pandas

tab = pandas.DataFrame(tabula.read_pdf('..\PDFs\Ala.pdf', pages ='all')[0])
```